# Double double precision in PostGis in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, precision

This is my SQL:

```
    SELECT st_asText(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(52.000000000012345678 21.0000000000123456789)'))
    SELECT st_asText(ST_MakePoint(52.000000000012345678, 21.0000000000123456789))
```

But response is:

```
    POINT(52.0000000000123 21.0000000000123)
```

I need double double precision in PostGis. How can i fix it?

Comment: You need *double double precision* !  What are you doing, positioning quarks ?

Comment: Quoting [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude): "Thirteen decimal places will pin down the location to 111,111/10^13 = about 1 angstrom, around half the thickness of a small atom."

Answer (score 3):

That **is** already double precision. Single precision coordinates would trim after the sixth decimal whereas double offers [15 digits of precision](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-numeric.html). You're trying to set a point with 18 decimal positions.

Also is important to note that the number of decimal places a double can hold depends on the numbers to the left of the decimal separator. ([see OSGeo rants abot that](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/ToleranceDiscussion)) so you're using two digits for the integer part (52 and 21) and you have 13 digits left to play with, which is exactly what you're getting in the response.

Comment: Well, the OP asked for "double double", meaning quadruple precision floats (128 bit floats in IEEE 754) or something along those lines.